# Pass environment variable to a java class using dockerfile

Tags: java, shell, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to pass the environment variable to shell script which runs the java class  using docker. and i am getting errors and not able to execute it.

test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
java -cp s3fileprocess-1.0.1.jar com.wt.test.S3FileProcess $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID  $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY $bucketName $keyName $uploadFileName $downloadFile
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM java:8
ADD . /home/test
WORKDIR /home/test
RUN chmod +x ./test.sh
ENTRYPOINT ./test.sh
```

build the image:

```
docker build -t test .
```

Run the container:

```
docker run  -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=A***** \
-e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=w***** \
-e bucketName=I***** \
-e keyName=index.php \
-e uploadFileName=/home/test/index.php \
-e downloadFile=/home/index.php \ 
test
```

Error:

```
docker: Error parsing reference: " " is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

i am able to pass environment variables to a simple shell script file using docker without any issue.

This works perfectly:
test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
echo $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
echo $uploadFileName
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM amazonlinux
ADD . /home/test  
WORKDIR /home/test  
RUN chmod +x ./test.sh   
ENTRYPOINT ./test.sh
```

Build image:

```
docker build -t test .
```

Run container:

```
docker run  -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=A*********** \
-e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=w************ \
-e uploadFileName=/home/test/index.php \
test  /bin/bash
```

Can anyone help me figure out what i am doing wrong here? how to pass environment variables to a java class using dockerfile?

Comment: Your information looks perfectly ok. Have you not tagged the image?

Comment: Please check if image is running and then check if the new image name is valid.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. the same command works fine!